# VBA CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open strURL does not work

Tags: vba, ms-access

I ran into a weird VBA problem: having a string variable `strURL` containing a valid URL

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open strURL                ' does *not* work
```

whereas

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open strURL & vbNullString ' works
```

while "works" means opens browser with given URL as intended.
Code resides in an unbound form module in Access (current Office 365 version).

Although I found my workaround, I'd really like to understand the reason *why* (and leave a hint to others that may run into the same problem)!

Comment: Shell sometimes prefers variants over (eg) strings, so try declaring strURL as Variant if you have it as String.

Comment: confirmed: declaring `strURL` as variant works as expected. Does VBA convert the type to Variant in my workaround if I state `strURL & vbNullString`!?

Comment: I can't say for sure why concatenating vbNullString makes it "acceptable" - `TypeName(s & vbNullString)` where `s` is declared as String still outputs "String"

Comment: @Tim Williams: Ok. Maybe you want to post your suggestion (declaring variable as `Variant` as an answer for that I can accept it. Although we don't know the background of this mess, I think it would suffice to help other people preventing the error I ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ron deBruin's notes on his page describing use of Shell to unzip:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm

Shell sometimes prefers variants over (eg) strings, so try declaring `strURL` as `Variant` if you have it as `String`